# C++ library like Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: c++

I had been using BeautifulSoup in Python for the past few weeks. Now that I would like to use C++, is there a similar library in C++?

Comment: What do you need in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you want something in C++ that loads either a HTML or XML file into some read-write object hierarchy such as a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) tree, which is also queryable?

Yes, I'm going to have exactly the same headache - having recently aquired some modest skill with JQuery in JavaScript - if I ever want to enjoy the same dexterity back in the C++ world.  We don't seem particularly spolit for choice - plenty of options for handling XML, but [HTML parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers) seem quite thin on the ground (I'm a bit suprised because C/C++ is a popular choice for writing web-browsers in).

I'm going to recommend [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).  Particularly the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) support (see its [architecture](http://www.xmlsoft.org/architecture.html), and also note its HTML and XML parsers).  libxml2 is actually a library that BeautifulSoup uses!  (Ideally you'd want this recommendation to come from someone who has actually used libxml2, but I'm afraid my experience is with Xerces, Xalan and RapidXML, none of which provide the HTML support you want).